# simple game - fair value

Tags: price, game

Suppose a person A has the following game:

- there are 2 red balls, 2 green balls and 1 white ball in a bag
- you take 1 ball (don't put it again in the bag) and then a second ball
- if you take the white ball, you win 10$.

The question is : what is the price of this game ?
Suppose this is $c$ , then one can find that : $E[X] = 4-c$, with $X=10-c$ or $X=-c$. So in order to have a fair game : $c=4$.
Is it the good answer to find the $fair$ price of this game ?  I think there is the notion of martingale for the "fair" price. Fair price would mean that A, and the person who plays have equal chances in this game. And because it's "fair" we would have $E[Wealth_{t}|F_{s}]=Wealth_{s}$ with $Wealth=X$ actually. So we have to write $E[X]=0$ in order to find c, right ? I would like an intuitive answer (I know the numerical part is right ^^) by using some concepts of the option pricing theory (?).

Comment: The fair price should be the expectation of the payoff you receive from this game. That is, the payoff is a martingale. However, as there are only two draws in this game, the use of martingale theory is not necessary. Note that there are two scenarios that you have a pay, that is, 

*white ball the first time and any other the next, or any other the first and the white next*.

The expectation is $\frac{1}{5}\times 10 + \frac{4}{5}\times \frac{1}{4} \times 10 = 4$, which is the price.

Comment: - The payoff is a martingale $because$ it's a $fair$ game ? So as I said we can use the relation for the wealth process above ?
- Ok for your solution that is more straightforward, but is my solution right ? (to write $E[X]=0$ because it's a fair game and so the persons A and B have equals chance to win ?)

Comment: I think yours is also fine.